# super().__init__() является аналогом base: в c#?

Tags: c#, python

`super().__init__()` является аналогом `base:` в c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base` может использоваться в двух контекстах:

1. для доступа к полям родительского класса
2. для вызова конструктора родительского класса

Для первого типа использования аналогом `base` является `super()`.
Для второго типа использования `super().__init__` является аналогом `base`.

В питоне нет неявного использования конструктора и поэтому это одно и то же. `super()` возвращает ссылку на базовый класс, а ее можно использовать для доступа к методам или атрибутам класса, в частности для вызова специального метода `__init__`, который является конструктором.